# I am an object, I am below you

Tags: riddle

> I am an object.
>
> I am below you.
>
> When you remove my first letter, I'll be above you.
>
> When you remove my first two letters, I disappear.
>
> What am I?

Please I've been trying to unravel the answer to this puzzle.... I'll appreciate the answers very much

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: my friend asked me

Answer (score 6):

The answer could be

> Chair

I am below you

> You tend to sit on a chair

When you remove my first letter I'll be above you

> Hair - usually on top of your head

When you remove my first two letters I disappear

> Air - invisible to the human eye.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether we should be answering without knowing the source.

Comment: @noedne why is that? I am quite new to Puzzling SE so I don't understand that sort of thing...

Comment: @JamesDouglas Puzzles from outside sources need to be properly attributed. Without knowing the source, the puzzle could be from an ongoing contest, part of the reason for my hesitation.

Comment: @noedne Oh I see thanks for explaining that